# Android Admob/Ad manager sample code crashing

Tags: java, android, admob, google-ad-manager

The code i am using can be found at https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/releases/download/5.8/Java_NativeAdsExample_AdManager.zip  also available at https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/5.8/java/admanager/NativeAdsExample

There have been no changes to the code running it as is shows the ads but the ads with images in them (Video asset ads are working fine) crashes the app when clicked on them.

This is running  a google test ad and not the orignal one and other ad examples are working fine

The stack trace of the crash is

```
2021-06-17 15:09:19.902 32360-32410/com.google.example.gms.nativeadsexample W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
2021-06-17 15:09:19.916 32360-32404/com.google.example.gms.nativeadsexample W/Ads: Update ad debug logging enablement as false
.....
.....
2021-06-17 15:02:18.204 17881-17881/com.google.example.gms.nativeadsexample D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-06-17 15:02:18.205 17881-17881/com.google.example.gms.nativeadsexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.example.gms.nativeadsexample, PID: 17881
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'bak com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.eventattestation.a.a()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ac.ay(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@211512000@211512000057.367949677.367949677:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.y.ay(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@211512000@211512000057.367949677.367949677:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.gmsg.z.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@211512000@211512000057.367949677.367949677:15)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.util.c.a(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.q.u(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@211512000@211512000057.367949677.367949677:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.q.t(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@211512000@211512000057.367949677.367949677:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ai.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at apc.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@211512000@211512000057.367949677.367949677:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.f.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@211512000@211512000057.367949677.367949677:1)
        at apc.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@211512000@211512000057.367949677.367949677:0)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7032)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
2021-06-17 15:02:18.223 17881-18238/com.google.example.gms.nativeadsexample I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2021-06-17 15:02:18.223 17881-18238/com.google.example.gms.nativeadsexample I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2021-06-17 15:02:18.229 17881-18239/com.google.example.gms.nativeadsexample I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2021-06-17 15:02:18.229 17881-18239/com.google.example.gms.nativeadsexample I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2021-06-17 15:02:18.249 17881-17881/com.google.example.gms.nativeadsexample I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17881 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Same here. Its crashing here too